# Explanation for a line of code in c++ related to bitshifts

Tags: c++, bit-shift

I don't want someone to explain how the following code works (it checks whether an int is pandigital) as I should be doing that myself. I just need help understanding line 8 specifically. I don't know what the | is doing.

```
private bool isPandigital(long n) {
    int digits = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int tmp;

    while (n > 0) {
        tmp = digits;
        digits = digits | 1 << (int)((n % 10) - 1);
        if (tmp == digits) {
            return false;
        }

        count++;
        n /= 10;
    }
    return digits == (1 << count) - 1;
}
```

Comment: Finally figured out how to format the code part. Ctrl-K for the win! Remarkable what actually reading can do for you. Though I feel like that should be at the top of the description when you click code, as its really not that obvious.

Comment: This code will never return true.

Comment: Are you sure? I got it from: http://www.mathblog.dk/project-euler-32-pandigital-products/ I should think if it didn't work he wouldn't have been able to solve the problem.

Comment: @Dani Care to give a reason it won't work? I think it will work just fine with an input such as `123`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know others have already explained that it's a bitwise OR, but I'd like to give my own interpretation.

`digits = digits | X` will copy all the 1 bits from X into digits.

`digits = digits | 1 << Y` will "set" a single bit in digits  - it will set the Yth bit.

So, each loop sets a bit in digits.

Comment: Thank you this brought together all the pieces that I have learned in the last 30 minutes. Your basically raising 2 to the yth power which in binary is simply the yth bit. That bit in digits is then set to be a 1 regardless of what it is. Then the further lines in the code check to see if digits has changed if it has it shows that bit in digits was originally 0 so we know that it is the first time we are seeing that number. You do that for all numbers 1 through 9 and if digits always changes then every number is contained once so its pandigital. Is that correct?

Comment: Yep, that's what my mental debugger is telling me :-)  I do notice that this will not work if the input has a `0`, because that will do a negative shift.  And i'm not sure of the definition of pandigital, but this code will return true for `123`, `1234`, `123456789` etc. and any jumbles, but not `124 `, `2345`, etc.

Comment: How do I stalk you on this site so that I'm notified of questions you ask and answer? I ask this as your answer was so clear and concise that I feel obligated to read more of what you write in an attempt to learn some of the deeper intricacies of c++.

Answer (score 1):

| is bitwise or. But the code checks whether an int of length n has all digits 1..n. This is different from palindrome check.  That line sets's (i-1)'th bit of `digits` to 1 if the last digit of `n` is `i`. [BTW, the code is wrong: if `n` contains a zero-digit, that line will trigger "undefined behavior": shifting an integer by a negative amount gives an undefined result.]

The code uses an integer `digits` to represent a set of digits. You can learn more about the technique by searching for bit sets.

Comment: It checks for pandigitalness as defined as having the numbers 1-9. The code isn't incorrect as its made for a project euler problem and so the integers are never supposed to contain a zero. But I can see potential problems down that road.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be performing a Bitwise Or.

Comment: `Appears??` `|` is the Bit wise Or Operator, What else do you think it could do?

Comment: Check here for a more thorough explanation of Bitwise Or: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html

Comment: Als -> Yes. ;-). Assuming he isn't using some arcane variant of C++.

Answer (score 0):

`|` is a bitwise `OR`

A bitwise OR takes two bit patterns of equal length and performs the logical inclusive OR operation on each pair of corresponding bits. The result in each position is 1 if the first bit is 1 OR the second bit is 1 OR both bits are 1; otherwise, the result is 0.

Example:

```
10010000
01010000
--------
11010000
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation

Answer (score 0):

`|` is a bitwise or.

So the line is doing `digits = digits | (1 << (int)((n % 10) - 1));`

Comment: You got your parentheses wrong, << has higher precedence than |.

Comment: @zvrba: Downvote is supposed to help people improve. Isn't it?

Comment: Is that the same thing as digits = digits | (int)((n%10)-1))<<1

Comment: @emschorsch: No way! they are different. your code is simply multiplying `(int)((n%10)-1))` by 2, while your original code multiplies `1` by power of 2, where the power = `(int)((n%10)-1))`

Comment: Oh wow ya should've gotten that was stuck on only the variable can be multiplied for some reason. Thanks